# Percentage of students that have purchased rewards

Tags: mysql

I have a Reward System based on MySQL/PHP. Teachers award students points; students can then purchase rewards using their accrued points.

What I'd like to do is display a single percentage figure of *students who have purchased rewards*.

This sounds quite simple, but in practice it may be a little bit more complicated to achieve.

- I don't have a list of students in the database, I simply have `transactions`
- If a student has received a point, their `ID` will be displayed in the `transactions` table under the `Recipient_ID` column

The `transactions` table looks like: `Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`.

The `purchases` table looks like: `Purchase_ID`, `Datetime`, `Reward_ID`, `Quantity`, `Student_ID`, `Student_Name` (blank), `Date_DealtWith`, `Date_Collected`

So, for example, I can list all of my student IDs using `SELECT DISTINCT Recipient_ID
FROM transactions`.

All I basically need is:

- [students] A count of students with a point+ (i.e. `Recipient_ID` in `transactions`)
- [purchases] A count of students with a purchase+ (i.e. `Student_ID` in `purchases)
- [purchases] / [students] * 100

.. but I'm not sure how to do that in one query!

---

**EDIT: Insert Statements***

purchases...

```
INSERT INTO `purchases` (`Purchase_ID`, `Datetime`, `Reward_ID`, `Quantity`, `Student_ID`, `Student_Name`, `Date_DealtWith`, `Date_Collected`) VALUES
(1, '2011-09-27 16:55:16', 1, 1, 34240, '', '2011-09-27 16:55:16', '2011-12-12 15:45:43'),
(2, '2011-09-28 13:02:26', 1, 1, 137636, '', '2011-09-27 16:55:16', '2011-09-27 16:55:16'),
(3, '2011-09-29 11:29:09', 1, 1, 137685, '', NULL, NULL);
```

transactions...

```
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`) VALUES
(1, '2011-09-07', 36754, 34401, 5, 6, 'Gave excellent feedback on the new student notebook'),
(2, '2011-09-07', 34972, 137615, 10, 9, 'Helping TG'),
(6, '2011-09-07', 35006, 90185, 2, 1, '');
```

Comment: I think the key to your question is `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` functions. If you post the create statements, and a few insert statements for dummy data, I can write the query to select what you want

Comment: looks like you got your answer - here it is as a gist: https://gist.github.com/2029991 (self contained test code can be pasted into mysql console)

Comment: Thanks very much Billy - very thorough. Sorry I didn't get to award you the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an ugly version, which manages to avoid doing the count of students from `transactions` twice through a hackish join between 2 sub-queries.

```
SELECT
 numrewards_students,
 numpurchase_students,
 numpurchase_students / numrewards_students * 100.0
FROM
 ( SELECT 0 AS joiner, COUNT( DISTINCT Recipient_ID ) AS numrewards_students FROM transactions ) AS trs
JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS joiner, COUNT( DISTINCT Student_ID ) AS numpurchase_students FROM purchases ) AS prs ON trs.joiner = prs.joiner
```

Another version, I'm not certain will work without a `FROM` clause in the sub-query - I can't remember if MySQL will permit this:

```
SELECT 
  numrewards_students,
  numpurchase_students,
  numpurchase_students / numreward_students * 100.0
FROM 
(
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) Recpipient_ID AS numrewards_students FROM transactions) AS numrewards_stduents,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) Student_ID  AS numpurchases_students FROM purchases) AS numpurchase_stduents
)
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Where does the `numrewards_students` etc. come from?

Comment: @dunc They are aliases produced by the subqueries.

Comment: I can't get either working - `#1054 - Unknown column 'numreward_students' in 'field list'` for the first, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tcounts' at line 9` from the second. If I thus remove the `tcounts` bit on your code (typo?) then I get `#1054 - Unknown column 'numrewards_students' in 'field list'`.

Comment: @dunc For the first one, `numreward_students` should have been `numrewards_students` in the division statement.

Comment: @dunc For the second, see the updated syntax. Based on a test I just did, I think it should work to remove the table alias `tcount` and alias each of the 2 columns inside the `()`